# Lazy loaded angular module without router-outlet not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have a `Services` lazy loaded module and inside that module I have another lazy loaded module `ServiceProvider` inside it.

**Can i use the `router-outlet` of the parent module Services without defining a separate outlet for the child lazy module ?**

The thing is that I dont want to define a separate component for putting the router outlet inside the child module.

These are the routes of the services module.

```
export const SERVICES_ROUTES: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ServicesComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'list', component: ServicesListComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'tips_and_laws_list', component: ConstructionTipsAndLawsListComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'service_provider_list', loadChildren: './../services/service-providers/service-providers.module#ServiceProvidersModule',
          },
          {
            path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

When i navigate to `service_provider_list`, i dont have a router-outlet inside that module.

Routes for the service providers module.

```
export const SERVICES_PROVIDER_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: ServiceProviderListComponent,

  }
];
```

**Can i load the `ServiceProviderListComponent` without a router-outlet inside the `ServiceProvidersModule` ?**

Comment: You would really really help if you could post some code

Comment: @BrunoFenzl Updated with code.